# OpenCL dynamic parallelism enqueue_kernel() functionality

Tags: c++, c, opencl, gpgpu, amd-gpu

I am trying to use the functionality provided by OpenCL 2.0 to call kernels from within kernels but cannot seem to get it working.

For instance I have these kernels:

```
__kernel void test2(){
    printf("test2");
}
__kernel void test1(){
    void (^my_func)(void) = ^{test2();};
    printf("test1");
    enqueue_kernel(get_default_queue(), CLK_ENQUEUE_FLAGS_NO_WAIT, ndrange_1D(1, 1), my_func);
}
```

then I call test1 using :

```
    size_t globalWorkSize = 1;
    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &globalWorkSize, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

However it seems as though test1 now doesn't execute at all, printf("test1"); doesn't print anything, if I comment out the enqueue_kernel() call it does. The kernel compiles with no errors and I am using the "-cl-std=CL2.0" flag, very strange. What am I missing ? Thanks in advance.

I am running the AMD 3.0 OpenCL SDK on Windows with a 7900XT.

If I try and declare an ndrange_t variable for example the kernel runs just fine so I am assuming everything is set up correctly, yet the enqueue_kernel call seemingly bricks the whole thing as nothing else gets executed before or after the call. If I try and print the out the output of enqueue_kernel, again doesn't work, I am assuming something bad happens at runtime, this really baffles me.

Comment: Just to cover the low-hanging fruits: Your call to `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` does not check the return value for errors. Did you do so? Same for the `enqueue_kernel`, which may also return an error code

Comment: @Homer512 The clEnqueueNDRangeKernel call does not return any errors, I tried checking enqueue_kernel but as I explained nothing gets printed out, it's as if the kernel is never executed if the enqueue_kernel call is present.

Comment: I think AMD has more or less given up properly supporting OpenCL for all but its post Vega Instinct server GPU cards.

Comment: Try checking your ROCm version with rocminfo. Better late than never, according to this article, the 7900XT is now supported if you have ROCm 5.7.

Comment: I am on windows, I am using the AMD APP SDK 3.0, I guess I will look into using ROCm but last time I checked the support wasn't there for windows.

Comment: Doesn't look like this will help me, HIP doesn't support dynamic parallelism apparently.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what was wrong, apparently you also need another queue sperate from the one you use to call the kernel which spawns other kernels and this queue has to be created with clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties specifically and it needs to have the proper flags to allow queues on devices. For some reason no error codes signal the absences of this queue which is why this was so difficult to debug. I guess the kernel would crash at runtime since there was no queue.

So for instance adding the following lines fixed my issue :

```
cl_queue_properties properties[] = { CL_QUEUE_PROPERTIES, (cl_command_queue_properties)(CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE | CL_QUEUE_ON_DEVICE | CL_QUEUE_ON_DEVICE_DEFAULT), 0 };
cl_command_queue device_queue = clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties(context, device, properties, &err);
```

device_queue isn't actually explicitly used to launch anything, it just has to be created.